# How old are you? or What is your age?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage

Which is more common or used more and also the correct way of asking?

Comment: The former is much more common. The latter is almost never used; you might find it on a bureaucratic form to fill out or when being interrogated by an unsympathetic police officer. But you really should have asked this question on our sister site, [ELL.se].

Comment: @DanBron Thank you. What is the difference in these sites? My question was about usage, so I asked it here.

Comment: Both are technically correct.  The former is more casual, the latter more formal.  For instance, I would consider it more polite for the receptionist at a doctor's office to ask "What is your age?" rather than "How old are you?"

Comment: @lemm ELL is focused on people attempting to *learn* English, and e.g. find out which usages are more common among native speakers; the kinds of questions native speakers would not have to ask (because the questions wouldn't even occur to them). By contrast, this site (EL&U), is mostly focused towards linguists, etymologists, and people with a native command of English (either because they're born to it or they've developed an extremely advanced level of usage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"How old are you?" is the most common way of asking for someone's age (at least in Australia). The latter certainly sounds very formal and would usually be found on government forms and possibly used verbally in formal situations.

Comment: Ditto for American English.